# Is there a way to get the key from a list embedded in a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that, given a dictionary of restaurants, allows you to randomly pick a restaurant based on your choice of one of the values. For example, if you say you want a bakery then it will only give you bakeries.

I have only worked on the code for choosing the type of restaurant so far, and I am struggling with how to generate a random list. So I am checking for a value and, if it has it, would want to add the key to a list. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

```
import random 
Restaurants ={

"Eureka": ["American", "$$", "Lunch", "Dinner"],
"Le_Pain": ["Bakery", "$$", "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner"],
"Creme_Bakery": ["Bakery", "$", "Snack"]

}

list=[]

def simple_chooser():
    print('Would you like to lock a category or randomize? (randomize, type, price, or meal)')
    start= input() 
    if start=="randomize":
        return #completely random
    elif start=="type":
        print("American, Bakery, Pie, Ice_Cream, Bagels, Asian, Chocolate, Italian, Pizza, Thai, Mexican, Japanese, Acai, Mediterranean, or Boba/Coffee?")
        type=input()
        for lst in Restaurants.values():
           for x in lst:
                if x==type:
                    list.append(x)
                return(random.choice(list))
```

Comment: what is expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return completely random restaurant suggestions you need to create a list of all the types first and then you can choose one and return the names of the restaurants.

```
import random 
Restaurants ={

"Eureka": ["American", "$$", "Lunch", "Dinner"],
"Le_Pain": ["Bakery", "$$", "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner"],
"Creme_Bakery": ["Bakery", "$", "Snack"]

}

types = ['American', 'Bakery', 'Pie', 'Ice_Cream', 'Bagels', 'Asian', 'Chocolate', 'Italian', 
'Pizza', 'Thai', 'Mexican', 'Japanese', 'Acai', 'Mediterranean','Boba/Coffee']

    def simple_chooser():
        l=[]
        print('Would you like to lock a category or randomize? (randomize, type, price, or meal)')
        start= input() 
        if start=="randomize":
            type_random = random.choice(types)
            for k,v in Restaurants.items():
                if v[0] == type_random:
                    l.append(k)
    
        elif start=="type":
            print("American, Bakery, Pie, Ice_Cream, Bagels, Asian, Chocolate, Italian, Pizza, Thai, Mexican, Japanese, Acai, Mediterranean, or Boba/Coffee?")
            type_chosen=input()
            for k,v in Restaurants.items():
                if v[0] == type_chosen:
                    l.append(k)
    
        return(random.choice(l))
```

Also, you don't need to return in if-else statements. Once you have your list of Restaurants you can randomly choose a restaurant and return it.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you don't have the restaurant name, as you iterate on the `values`, you would have need something like

```
for name, props in Restaurants.items():
    if props[0] == type:
        list.append(name)
return (random.choice(list)) # wait for the whole list to be constructed
```

---

With a better naming (don't use `type` and `list` that are builtin methods)

```
def simple_chooser():
    start = input('Would you like to lock a category or randomize? (randomize, type, price, or meal)')
    if start == "randomize":
        return  # completely random
    elif start == "type":
        restaurant_type = input("American, Bakery, Pie, Ice_Cream, Bagels, Asian, Chocolate, Italian, "
                                "Pizza, Thai, Mexican, Japanese, Acai, Mediterranean, or Boba/Coffee?")
        matching_names = [name for name, props in Restaurants.items() if props[0] == restaurant_type]
        return random.choice(matching_names)
```

Answer (score 1):

You make processing difficult because of the design of your data structures.

Here's an idea which should be easily adapted to future needs.

```
import random
from operator import contains, eq

Restaurants = [
    {'name': 'Eureka', 'type': 'American', 'price': '$$', 'meal': ('Dinner',)},
    {'name': 'Le_Pain', 'type': 'Bakery', 'price': '$$', 'meal': ('Lunch', 'Dinner')},
    {'name': 'Creme_Bakery', 'type': 'Bakery', 'price': '$', 'meal': ('Snack',)}
]

def get_attr(k):
    s = set()
    for r in Restaurants:
        if isinstance(r[k], tuple):
            for t in r[k]:
                s.add(t)
        else:
            s.add(r[k])
    return s

def choose_restaurant():
    categories = ', '.join(Restaurants[0])
    while True:
        choice = input(f'Select by category ({categories}) or choose random: ')
        if choice == 'random':
            return random.choice(Restaurants)
        if choice in Restaurants[0]:
            choices = get_attr(choice)
            if (v := input(f'Select value for {choice} from ({", ".join(choices)}): ')) in choices:
                op = contains if isinstance(Restaurants[0][choice], tuple) else eq
                return [r for r in Restaurants if op(r[choice], v)]
        print('Invalid selection\x07')


print(choose_restaurant())
```

Restaurants is now a list of dictionaries which is easy to extend. You just need to make sure that each new restaurant has the same structure (keys). Also note that the 'meal' value is a tuple even if there's a single value